# VB6 to VB.NET conversions button style

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, vb6, controls

We have recently converted an old VB6 application to VB.NET via VS2008. The program is being launched via a c# WPF project that brings up the some of the VB.NET Forms ad hoc.

There is an issue with the way some of the controls that are being displayed.

If for example we add a new button (Button1) control like this:

[image]

When compiled it displays like this:

[image]

So the "Close" button was converted in and the "Button1" was added after conversion. The styles of the buttons are obviously being effect somewhere.

I have looked in the design file and I can't see anything obvious.

How is this handled?

Comment: You posted the same img url twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be due to the `Enable Visual Styles` Setting. I'm guessing this was not set to True when the project was upgraded? Possibly an automatic thing so that the application looks as similar to the original as possible.

More Info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984291(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks that worked, I added (System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles) to the main application that calls the VB forms